# Override default style behavior of TinyMCE on new element

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I was trying to search for a way to override default behavior of TinyMCE when it applies same styles to new elements. For example, when we apply some style to a paragraph and hit enter for new paragraph, it inherits same styles. Is it possible to override this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

You will have to register the keyup event and check for the ENTER key.
Then you check the actual node the caret is in and you may add/remove classes or whatever. Use the setup tinymce configuration parameter to add the handler:

```
 setup:function(ed){
      ed.on("keyup", function(e){
           if(e.keyCode == 13){ // ENTER
                var node = ed.selection.getNode();

                // do your magic here
           }                        
      });
 }
```

Comment: There isn't any configuration to stop this inheritance of style to new elements?

Comment: i am still not very familiar with tinymce4, but in tinymce3 it is not possible